# Convert interactive python script to run in browser

Tags: python, web, browser

I have written a interactive python script, which takes input from user and searches that keyword in logs and provides output in terminal.

I want to replicate this in web, where pop up screen asks for user input and runs the python script in background and displays output in browser.

I want to know using what technologies I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many web app frameworks for python that you could use such as Django or Flask. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) is a very easy to use framework that should be able to do your job without a problem so I'd definitely recommend checking it out.

For a more in depth comparison of Django, Flask and Pyramid you can read through this article: https://www.airpair.com/python/posts/django-flask-pyramid